# Adding music in android studio (java, MediaPlayer)

Tags: java, android

```
   buttonMusic = findViewById(R.id.buttonMus);

    musicSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    buttonClick();
}

private Button buttonMusic;
private MediaPlayer musicSound;

public void buttonClick() {
    buttonMusic.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    soundPlay(musicSound);

                }
            }
    );
}

public void soundPlay(MediaPlayer sound) {
    if (sound.isPlaying()) {
        sound.stop();

    }else {
        sound.start();
        sound.setLooping(true);
    } }
```

Hello.
The code launches the music, is able to stop it, but it wont play again after pressing the play button, after pausing the song that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't pausing song, you are `stop()`ing it. use `sound.pause()` for pausing :)

after `stop()` `MediaPlayer` you have to prepare it again, use `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()`. `MediaPlayer.create(` makes that for you at the beginning, also if you would create `MediaPlayer` using its constructor you would also want to `prepare()`/`preapreAsync()` before calling `start()` in onClick

check out [state diagram of `MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#StateDiagram)